# How can I find what /dev my DVD-drive is?

Tags: macos, mac, dd, optical-drive

I'm on Mac OS X, have a DVD in the DVD-drive and can look at it in the Finder. I'd like to try to create an iso of it by using the `dd` command. But to do that I need to know what device to use as an input. How can I find what device my DVD-drive is?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Put a disk into the drive, wait until OS X mounts it, and then type the following command in the Terminal:

```
$ mount
[⋮]
/dev/disk2 on /Volumes/MyDisk (cd9660, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)
```

In my case, the drive is located at `/dev/disk2`.

You can use `drutil` as well.

```
# drutil status
 Vendor   Product           Rev 
 MATSHITA DVD-R   UJ-857D   KBVB

           Type: DVD+RW               Name: /dev/disk2
[⋮]
```

Comment: what are the chances for me to find you here! :D

Answer (score 11):

Finally found a way. Not sure if it is the best, but it works anyways:

```
df -h
```

c",)

Comment: It's also a working solution, since `df` displaying the free disk space on mounted file systems showing their device name as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suddenly discovered. My first thinking was that I could try to match it up with the size, but then discovered that it stood right there which was which :p

Answer (score 4):

Start Utilites, Disk Util.  Click the drive or partition on the left, then the blue i/info icon in the toolbar.  The disk identifier is the name to be used after /dev/

Comment: For me, the disk identifier is the volume label (*MyDisk*), which is the same as the mount point under `/mnt`, and not the device name under `/dev`, which is `/dev/disk2`.

Comment: +1 because it solved my problem, which was trying to eject a DVD I'd unmounted.

Comment: this is the best answer because in my case I can't mount my device.

Answer (score 3):

Just embodied the diskutil incantation and awk in a script to recite CD device names:

May be handy for future reuse; I'm about to use it in my CD ripping kit.

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Scan the output of diskutil and report the CD devices.
#   - Cameron Simpson <cs@zip.com.au> 31mar2016
#

set -ue

diskutil list \
| awk '/^\// { device=$1 }
       $1 == "0:" && $2 == "CD_partition_scheme" { print device }
      '
```

Source code: https://bitbucket.org/cameron_simpson/css/src/tip/bin/osx-cd-device

Answer (score 2):

thankfully, OS X has several options. in **System Profiler**, choose **Serial-ATA**, then in the device tree frame choose your device. it shows up as **BSD Name**.

**df** is fine but it displays with the partition (volume mounted as) info, rather than the device itself. e.g. a drive shows up as **/dev/disk0s2** where the device itself is **disk0**; **s2** is the volume mounted on **/**  ..for most applications this is usable

**diskutil list** displays all devices and partitions

Answer (score 2):

You can find the path of a disk using a built-in tool on macOS.

1. Go into **Disk Utility**.
2. Select your drive by its name, such as `DUAL BOOT` in my case.
3. Open the info panel by its shortcut, right-clicking the disk in the list, or as the picture shows.

[image: Info button]

4. Locate the row named 'BSD device node'.

[image: 'Get Info' with /dev/ info]

The path will be `/dev/disk2s1`, based on the value of that row.

Comment: Device is listed on the first window, no need to press Info

Answer (score 1):

You can check for devices which have no free space on them (will be the case with burned CDs / DVDs):

```
df -h | grep Volumes | grep "100%" | rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev
```