# How do manually mount hard drive on mac?

Tags: macos, mount, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

My mac [recently gave up](https://serverfault.com/questions/328548/mac-osx-hard-disk-gives-invalid-peof-how-do-i-back-up-data/328558#328558) and I'm trying to salvage whatever data I can from the hard drive. I was able to boot using the OSX Installation CD and fire up Disk Utility that basically told me that the drive could not be repaired and I need to format it. My question - how can I manually mount it (from Terminal) and try to recover some of my data? I figured that if Disk Utility can see it, perhaps I could too. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

To mount disks:

**diskutil list**

see your drive and note id#, then:

**diskutil mountDisk /dev/diskn**

where n is the # you id'ed in diskutil list

Comment: `sudo diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk2s1` is what I had to use

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
mount /dev/disk1s10
```

And replace disk1s10 with the identifier of your drive.

Comment: There are plenty of disk* entries in `/dev`. How can I know which one is my actual drive? thanks again.

Comment: There are a few ways that I can think of. First get a list of all mounted drives before mounting the old drive. After you mount the old drive, view the list again - you can id it by process of elimination. There were a few other methods found in this SU post: http://superuser.com/questions/114515/how-can-i-find-what-dev-my-dvd-drive-is
`drutil` and `df` looked like the most effective methods

Comment: you can know the identifier doing `diskutil list disk2` (i.e for disk2)