# Mac OS 10.9 external hfs formated disk access via terminal mount command?

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, mount

I have a 2Tb harddisk connceted via USB toaster to my MacMini Mavericks. It was used to recuperate as much data as possible from my son's MacBook Pro (OS 10.6.8) before reformatting and reinstalling OS 10.

```
DiskUtil list shows:    
/dev/disk0   
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       
IDENTIFIER    
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0   
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1 
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            467.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                32.0 GB    disk0s4

/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       
IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SEAGATE_BU              2.0 TB     disk1s2

/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       
IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Seagate2TSL             1000.0 GB disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS SeaGate2T               999.9 GB  disk2s3
```

I've tried the following sudo mounts:

```
sudo mount -t hfs /dev/disk2s2/Volumes/Seagate2TSL/
sudo mount -uw -t hfs /dev/disk2s2/Volumes/Seagate2TSL/
sudo mount -uw -t hfs, local, nosuid, journaled, noowners /dev/disk2s2/Volumes/Seagate2TSL/
```

Each time, Terminal asks for my password and then gives me the "usage:"  list. Obviously, there is a syntax error in this thing somewhere. I am not a real terminal expert, but I *did* read the "man mount" pages and I found some examples on the internet, especially here.

Is is possible to tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for the link using diskutil list and mountDisk.
I've tried that, it mounts the disk successfully, but when I try to cd into that Volume, it tells me permission is denied; or if I catalog it (ls -la), Terminal lists all the files it copied, but they all have the suffix "permission denied".

This is curious, as this external disk was formatted and OS 10.6 was installed using the same password I'm using on the MacMini. Unfortunately the original MacBook Pro is no longer working (it won't boot up from its internal disk). Is there any way I can get around this read protection?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the DiskUtiil example. I can mount it but then "permission denied" prevents me from accessing the contents. Is there a super user way around this locked disk? Its password is the same as the Mini it's connected to.

Comment: Once you can mount the volume, just Get Info on it & check "Ignore ownership on this volume"

Comment: Thanks for the Get info info. I`ve tried that, even after booting into BootCamp (Windows 7) I can see it, read some of it and change ownership, etc (properties), but if I do that or  click Ignore Ownership as you suggested and re-lock the Get Info window on the Mac side, it doesn't give me any better access. Again: there must be a super user way to override the locks barring acces.

Comment: 'Ignore' really ought to do that totally. All perms 'off' - as though you own everything. Not sure that will carry through to Windows, though, that's a Mac/nix ignore. Was the drive used as a Time Machine drive, or is it a clone of the original drive? Your question is not totally clear as to how this 'recuperate before reinstall' is being done.

Comment: My son's MacBook Pro has disk problems. I Carbon Copy Cloner’ed much of the Pro's HDD to a 2Tb HDD. I connected the 2Tb HDD to the MacMini, ran /sbin/fsck -fy (OK) and then /sbin/mount -uw /. Now I’m stuck with the syntax of the mount command.  What does “mount” want that I'm not giving it (see list of “mounts” above)? Finder tells me I don't have permission to view the contents of the disk. I am not expert. Is there a way to access this external HDD via the Terminal? TIA

Comment: Did your son encrypt his home folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `diskutil` to mount.
Can you try some of the examples [in this link](https://superuser.com/questions/354827/how-do-manually-mount-hard-drive-on-mac)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that these two should be separate:

```
/dev/disk2s2/Volumes/Seagate2TSL/
```

Therefore, it should be:

```
/dev/disk2s2 /Volumes/Seagate2TSL/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'space' between your source and destination, hence the usage error.

Correction:

```
sudo mount -t hfs /dev/disk2s2 /Volumes/Seagate2TSL/
```